# cURL stopped working for HTTPS sites

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

All of a sudden, my PHP cURL implementation that access sites over SSL stopped working. After some digging around in the cURL response headers I discovered that the issue was a result of cURL not liking the sites SSL cert, giving the error:

> error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Now I didn't test it with other sites and I know there are solutions to add Mozilla's certs to cURL. But to get stuff to work I simply added a new cURL option to disable SSL validity checks (CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOS).

But I am still confused as to how this would stop working in just one day. It worked yesterday. The cert on the site didn't change and it is still a valid, unexpired, Verisign-issued cert.

Comment: Well something must have changed?  Maybe give some info on PHP/curl version and OS.  I'd grab the CA certs again, your cert bundle is probably what is hosed.  Good resource: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had this happen to me last month as well, and the only reason was that the SSL certificate in question was expired.  So I just renewed it and the curl ssl link worked again.  If you happen to deal with self-signed certificates it's the same deal btw, you either import it or switch of the verification.

That's the only thing I can think off but you state you already verified that...weird.  Any chance to take a peek at the site's certificate or is it private?  If you haven't changed anything it's almost certainly that something happened to the SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Try These two options in curl
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2